# Scope for "this" keyword in nested function?

Tags: javascript, this

Hi I have code that looks like this:

```
var myClass = {
    globalVar : {
        total : 100
    },
    myFunction : {
        getTotal : function() {
            return this.globalVar.total;
        }
    },
};

// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined 
alert(myClass.myFunction.getTotal() );
```

The keyword `this` returns **undefined**, why is that? Is it because I use `var myClass` instead of `function myClass()`?

Thanks

[EDIT]
Here's the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DarcFiddle/cg7Fk/

Comment: `myClass` isn't a class. It's just an object with properties.

Comment: `this` just turns out to be `myFunction` so it's like you're saying `myFunction.globalVar.total` which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Blender: JavaScript doesn't have classes, so bear with him. Even objects that mimic classes are still just objects with properties.

Comment: All you have to do here is `return myClass.globalVar.total;`

Comment: @Blender I see, so there's no way to use `this` to access the properties?

Comment: There is, but not in that way.

Comment: @DarcCode: You just have to understand what `this` really points to. `console.log(this)` in that function and you'll see that it's not really `undefined`.

Comment: @PSL Thanks, it works, but is there DRY-er method? I want `myClass` to be easily reusable even if the name changes.

Comment: @DarcCode this is DRY-er according to your current definition. It cannot be reusable. Read about first class object, javascript functions, prototypes etc... Because you don't have getter/setter for total anyways. Also `this` is not what is undefined.. it is `globalVar` that you were searching in that context of `this` which is just the function `getTotal` itself

Comment: **@Blender** Thanks, `this` does refer to `myFunction`. **@PSL** I guess I should use `function myClass` for DRY-er, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` just turns out to be `myFunction` so it's like you're saying `myFunction.globalVar.total` which doesn't exist.

You **could** make it re-usable like this if you wanted.

```
function Food(cost) {
    this.getTotal = function () {
        return cost + (cost * 0.05); // add 5%
    };
}

var sandwich = new Food(2.50);

alert( sandwich.getTotal() ); // 2.625
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thetenfold/HvHxR/

---

There are many ways to make a "class" *(so to speak)*.
This is not the only way, but it's a decent way.

Comment: Someone is downvoting all my recent answers without comments. Why do I even participate in this site? Most people here are cruel and nothing is done about it.

Comment: Hi thanks, it is exactly what I wanted. Sorry about the troll, maybe you can report it to admin (are there admins in SO?)

Comment: Idk. Anyways, you're welcome. You can ask me whatever if you get lost again, just PM/Chat me or whatever this site has.

Comment: @JoeSimmons serial downvotes would be reversed automatically..If you are facing this problem again you can post it in the meta.stackoverflow..Action would be taken accordingly..:)

Comment: They downvoted me 3 times in 4 minutes. I have a feeling this isn't quite enough to be "serial downvoting" so nothing will get done about it. I won't post on meta because they'll treat me like dirt for it.

Answer (score 2):

this is the scope of the object that you assign to myFunction at this point.

Comment: Thanks, at first I thought it refers to `myClass`

Answer (score 1):

As Blender says in comments, that is not a class. What you wanted is probably this:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    return {
        globalVar : {
            total : 100
        },
        getTotal : function() {
            return this.globalVar.total;
        }
    };
};

alert(new MyClass().getTotal() );
```